# How to put generic Type (T) as parameter?

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I have this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

on the method signature for this method:

```
 public static void SendMessage(string queuName, T objeto)
        {
            QueueClient Client =QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "Empresa");
            BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(objeto);
            message.ContentType = objeto.GetType().Name;
            Client.Send(new BrokeredMessage(message));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify the type parameter.
You can do that in 2 ways:

Either you define them at the method definition (which is the way to go in your case, because your method is static):

`public static void SendMessage<T>(string queuName, T objeto)`

Or you can specify them on the class definition (for instance methods):

```
class MyClass<T>{
    public void SendMessage(string queuName, T objeto){}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void SendMessage<T>(string queuName, T objeto)
{
    QueueClient Client =QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "Empresa");
    BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(objeto);
    message.ContentType = objeto.GetType().Name;
    Client.Send(new BrokeredMessage(message));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for your example is:

```
public static void SendMessage<T>(string queuName, T objeto)
{
// Type of T is
Type t = typeof(T);
// Obtain Name
string name = t.Name
// Create another instance of T
object to = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
// etc.
}
```

In general:

```
T method<T>(T param) where T: restrictions //new() for example
{ return (T)Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); }
```